# How to use monster skill in the field?

Tags: monster-hunter-stories

I read around the internet that it is possible to use Qurupeco's skill "Monster Call" to call for a certain monster on the field.

My question is, how do I actually use Monster Call?

Where is the option located?

I can't seem to find it.

Obs: I'm playing the mobile version, not the 3ds original one.

Comment: Please consider leaving a comment before downvoting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up figuring it out by myself.

It's not a menu option.

You just gotta be riding on the monster which has the skill you want to use, then another button will pop on the screen, an "Action" button.
[image: Before riding]
[image: Riding]